# How may I execute the doctest I'm seeing under pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, doctest

I bought a book to learn Python, and downloaded its sources from [here](https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code).

It's first chapter shows me this structure, under *PyCharm* :

[image]

If I can run `frenchdeck.py`, which displays nothing for itself : it's a class,
I have no way to execute the `frenchdeck.doctest` I'm seeing.

- No run option
- No right click button leading to anything that would launch a test
- Editing its content, replacing:
  `beer_card = Card('7', 'diamonds')`
  by
  `beer_card = Card('8', 'diamonds')`
  has no repercussions, nowhere...

How this kind of test (?) (maybe I'm misleading and they aren't) is intended to work, and check something?

PS : I've found two other questions about `doctest` on *Stack Overflow*, but they didn't solved my problem.

Comment: try this - https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html

Comment: your link says : "If you run example.py directly from the command line, doctest works its magic:

`$ python example.py`

There’s no output! That’s normal, and it means all the examples worked. Pass `-v` to the script, and doctest prints a detailed log of what it’s trying, and prints a summary at the end:" So I've tried `python3 frenchdeck.py -v` and there's still no output.

Comment: `python -m doctest <project_path>/frenchdeck.doctest`. If you pass a `.py` file instead, `doctest` is smart enough to extract tests from comments